# Вывод информации в консоль

Tags: linux, bash

Как вывести результат команды `ping ya.ru` в консоль, отображая только последние пять символов каждой строки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ping ya.ru | grep -o '.\{7\}$'
```

Напечатает:

> 61.1 ms
> 47.8 ms
> 52.9 ms
> =127 ms
> 5.10 ms
> 54.8 ms
> =141 ms
> 91.9 ms
> 61.1 ms
> =330 ms
> =167 ms
> =256 ms
> 59.2 ms
> =166 ms

А если Вам необходимо получить более корректные данные,то можно использовать  команду:

```
ping ya.ru | cut -d "=" -f4-
```

которая совершенно точно напечает будь то 5, 6, или 7 символов, которые идут после третьего знака "=" в каждой строке:

> 58.9 ms
> 56.7 ms
> 315 ms
> 274 ms
> 235 ms

Comment: Пять, а не семь ;)

Comment: @0andriy, просто я не понял,  что  там выводить на 5 символов!

Answer (score 2):

последние `n` символов можно извлечь из строки, содержащейся в переменной, с помощью оператора:

```
${переменная: -n}
```

или:

```
${переменная:(-n)}
```

а для того, чтобы обработать поток строк, можно воспользоваться, например, оператором цикла `while`.

---

пример:

```
$ ping -c 1 ya.ru | while read line; do echo ${line: -5}; done
data.
.3 ms

s ---
e 0ms
00 ms
```

---

доп. чтение:

- [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)
- [Looping Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html)
- [Bash Builtin Commands: read](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-read)

Comment: А сразу хочу поинтересоватся, с ` awk` это сработает?)

Comment: @Максим, программы *bash* и *awk* — это совершенно разные интерпретаторы, у них разные языки с разным синтаксисом.

Comment: Тоесть я могу вывести и отсортировать нужную мне информацию через `awk` так же в теории могу получить тот же вывод через `read line` но не наоборот?

Comment: @Максим, в принципе — да (правда, не понял насчёт «но не наоборот»).

Comment: это я о том что я не смогу потоковый вывод форматировать через `awk`. Просто было любопытно... Иначе говоря `awk` может обрабаьывать только файлы.

Comment: @Максим, не только файлы: `$ ping ya.ru | awk '{print $1}'` отлично работает.